# NSCoder vs NSDictionary, when do you use what?

Tags: cocoa

I'm trying to figure out how to decide when to use NSDictionary or NSCoder/NSCoding?

It seems that for general property lists and such that NSDictionary is the easy way to go that generates XML files that are easily editable outside of the application.

When dealing with custom classes that holds data or possibly other custom classes nested inside, it seems like NSCoder/NSCoding would be the better route since it will step through all the contained object classes and encode them as well when an archive command is used.

NSDictionary seems like it would take more work to get all the properties or data characteristics to a single level to be able to save it, where as NSCoder/NSCoding would automatically encode nested custom classes that implement the NSCoding interface.

Outside of it being binary data and not editable outside of your application is there a real reason to use one over the other? And along those lines is there an indicator of which way you should lean between the two? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple's documentation on [object graphs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Concepts/objectgraphs.html) has this to say:

> Mac OS X serializations store a simple hierarchy of value objects, such as dictionaries, arrays, strings, and binary data. The serialization only preserves the values of the objects and their position in the hierarchy. Multiple references to the same value object might result in multiple objects when deserialized. The mutability of the objects is not maintained.
>
> …
>
> Mac OS X archives store an arbitrarily complex object graph. The archive preserves the identity of every object in the graph and all the relationships it has with all the other objects in the graph. When unarchived, the rebuilt object graph should, with few exceptions, be an exact copy of the original object graph.

The way I interpret this is that, if you want to store simple *values*, serialization (using an NSDictionary, for example) is a fine way to go. If you want to store an *object graph* of arbitrary types, with uniqueness and mutability preserved, using archives (with NSCoder, for example) is your best bet.

You may also want to read Apple's [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/), of which the aforelinked page on object graphs is a part, as it covers this topic well.

Answer (score 5):

I am *NOT* a big fan of using NSCoding/NSCoder/NSArchiver (we need to pick a name!) to serialise an object graph to a file.

Archives created in this way are incredibly fragile. If you save an object of class Foo then by golly you need to make sure when you load the data back in you have a class Foo in your application.

This makes NSCoder based serialisation difficult from the perspective of sharing files with other applications or even forwards compatibility with your future application.

Comment: agreed.  i went down that route and ended up regretting it later.

Comment: I'm just learning this stuff, but it seems that `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` provide a way to [migrate schemas forward](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/compatibility.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001055-BCICFFGE) ... and by golly, you can use [-setClass:forClassName:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSKeyedUnarchiver/setClass%3aforClassName%3a) to change the class when you load the data back in.

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to list what I would recommend.

NSCoding can be ok in certain situations: if you're just doing something quick and simple (although you do have to write a lot of code - two methods per class to be serialised). It can also be ok if you're not worried about compatibility with other applications.

Export/import via property lists (perhaps using the NSPropertyListSerializaion class) is a fine solution. XML based plists are easy to create and edit. Main advantage to plists is that you're not tying the file format to just your application.

You can also create your own XML based file format and read/write to it using NSXMLDocument API and friends. This really isn't much more work than using property lists.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a bit confused, NSDictionary is a data structure, it also happens to implement the NSCoding protocol. So in essence, you could either put all your data into a NSDictionary and have that encode itself later on, or you can implement the NSCoding protocol and encode your object tree using the NSCoder API. Based on the type of NSCoder object passed in to the encodeWithCoder: method, is the output of your encoding.

Comment: I think it is pretty clear that he/she is referring to property list serialisation vs NSCoder serialisation.